# How to add a rectangle to view in Cocoa to border an image

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I am trying to add a rectangle to an `NSView` in Swift to create a frame for an image. The border needs to be red and to slightly cover the edge of the image.

This is the code I have so far:

```
let artworkView : NSImageView = NSImageView(frame: artworkRectangle)
artworkView.image = artwork
artworkView.rotate(byDegrees: 270)

myView.addSubview(artworkView)

let borderWidth : CGFloat = 3
let offset : CGFloat = borderWidth / 2

let artworkBorderRect : NSRect = NSRect(x: artworkRectangle.minX - offset, y: artworkRectangle.minY - offset, width: artworkRectangle.width + borderWidth, height: artworkRectangle.height + borderWidth)

let artworkBorderField = NSTextField(frame: artworkBorderRect)

artworkBorderField.drawsBackground = false
artworkBorderField.isBordered = true

artworkBorderField.textColor = NSColor.red

myView.addSubview(artworkBorderField)
```

I am using the `NSTextField` because this is easy to add to the `NSView` and I could not work out how to add an `NSRect` to a view. However, the result is an opaque border with insufficient width. Any suggestions as to how I can add stroke colour and width to this border?

Comment: If you don't want to use the layer then try a `NSBox`, it has a border.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to add borders to views is using Core Animation.

On MacOS, set `wantsLayer` on your custom view to true.

You can then set `view.layer.boderwidth` to a non-zero value. You can also set the view's layer's `borderColor`, `cornerRadius`, and various other properties of the view's backing `CALayer` (See the documentation on CALayer for more information.)

I created a simple demo app using Storybards, added a generic NSView to the view controller's scene, and gave it an IBOutlet "customView" to the view controller. I also added a label inside the view just for the heck of it.

Then I added this code in the view controller's viewDidLoad:

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    customView.wantsLayer = true // You need this line.
    guard let layer = customView.layer else { return }
    layer.borderWidth = 2
    layer.borderColor = NSColor.blue.cgColor
    layer.cornerRadius = 10
```

That results in a window that looks like this:

[image]

If you want a frame on an `NSImageView` you could do everything I outline above directly to the `NSImageView` , whether you create the `NSImageView` in a Storyboard or in code.

Comment: Added the following but no border?`artworkView.wantsLayer = true
        guard let layer = artworkView.layer else { return }
        layer.borderWidth = 3
        layer.borderColor = NSColor.blue.cgColor
        labelPageView.addSubview(artworkView)`

Comment: That should work. Try putting your image view inside a container NSView and applying the layer code to the container view.